# How to pass custom props to Single SPA child React apps?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, micro-frontend

I want to start my React microapp with props I'm passing from [Single SPA](https://single-spa.js.org/) ([customProps](https://single-spa.js.org/docs/api/#registerapplication)). The only way I've figured out is:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import singleSpaReact from 'single-spa-react';
import App from './where/my/root/is.js';

function domElementGetter() {
    return document.getElementById("mounting-node")
}

let EnhancedRootComponent = App; /* 1 */

const reactLifecycles = singleSpaReact({
    React,
    ReactDOM,
    rootComponent: EnhancedRootComponent, /* 1 */
    domElementGetter,
})

export const bootstrap = [
    (args) => {
        /* 2 */ EnhancedRootComponent = () => <App myArgs={args.thePropsIWannaPass} />;
        return Promise.resolve();
    },
    reactLifecycles.bootstrap,
];

export const mount = [reactLifecycles.mount];
export const unmount = [reactLifecycles.unmount];
```

This **does work** (I can see and use the passed props in my component) **but** I'm not completely OK with the fact that the root component changes in between calling `singleSpaReact` (1) and calling `bootstrap`(2). Would there be side effects to this that I'm not seeing now? Does anyone know a better approach for this?

Comment: If you build mostly React microfrontends then the model that comes with Piral may be more helpful here. https://github.com/smapiot/piral

Answer (score 4):

You have this value inside the props variable without this reassign.
Check this out:
Root-config.js, file responsible for passing prop to microfrontend

```js
import { registerApplication, start } from 'single-spa';
import * as isActive from './activity-functions';

registerApplication('@company/micro2', () => System.import('@company/micro2'), isActive.micro2);

registerApplication('@company/micro1', () => System.import('@company/micro1'), isActive.micro1, { "authToken": "test" });

start();
```

micro1 Root.tsx

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class Root extends React.Component {
  constructor(props: any){
    super(props)
  }

  state = {
    hasError: false,
  };

  componentDidCatch() {
    this.setState({ hasError: true });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>test</div>
    );
  }
}
```

console.log output:

```js
props:
   authToken: "test" <---- props which you pass
   name: "@company/micro1"
   mountParcel: ƒ ()
   singleSpa: {…}
   __proto__: Object
```

for more advance usage

```js
const lifecycles = singleSpaReact({
  React,
  ReactDOM,
  loadRootComponent: (props) => 
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve(() =>
      <Root {...props} test2={'test2'}/>)),
  domElementGetter,
});
```